# Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta3

Tags: entity-framework

The new version of ASPNET Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta3 has changed and I can't find OneToMany.
In the previous version this would work.

```
#region Table setup
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
public DbSet<UserCompany> UserComanies { get; set; }
#endregion
#region Setup DbContext
/// <summary>
/// Build data model in here.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="builder">Builder.</param>
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
  builder.Entity<User>().OneToMany(c => c.UserCompanies, uc => uc.User).ForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId).Required(true);
```

}

Does anyone know what to do in beta3?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now HasMany, as documented on the Wiki https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Using-EF7-in-Traditional-.NET-Applications